# Upright pi within Theorem environment

Tags: iso

Using the isomath trick to get upright greek pis works fine almost always, but not inside an amsthm theorem environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\let\mathpi\pi{}
\renewcommand{\pi}{\text{\textrm{\greektext{p}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} \pi \end{theorem}
not the same as $\pi$.
\end{document}
```

How to force pi to be the same inside the environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cpi}{%
  \textnormal{%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\math@version}{bold}=\z@\bfseries\fi
    \textpi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
$\cpi$
\end{theorem}

That's the same as $\cpi$. Also $\bm{\cpi}$.

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't redefine `\pi`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The default font doesn't have upright lowercase Greek letters. The `upgreek` package makes them available, from the `Euler` maths font, or from `Adobe Symbol`, depending on an option. I defines `\uppi` (and actually `\upalpha`,`\upbeta`, …).

Comment: Unfortunately, the upgreek package is not compatible with Computer Modern (fonts do not match).

Answer (score 0):

In `unicode-math`, an upright π is available as either `\uppi` (for compatibility with `\upgreek`), `\muppi`, or `\symup{pi}`.  ([See here for several examples.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432471/61644))  Several packages compatible with legacy NFSS also provide `\uppi`, including `\usepackage[lcgreek]{stix}` and `upgreek`.  The `\mathrm{\pi}` command might also be acceptable.